# Bot resistant website

Tags: authentication, bots

I'm building a website with lots of images and want to stop bots from accessing those images. So I'm looking something beyond cookies since bots can handle cookies. My idea is that all authentication should reside purely on the server side. Any ideas?

Someone suggested a website, that makes a user visit a thumbnail page first. Somehow visiting that page triggers a server side variable, which allows the main image to be displayed later. How can that be implemented.

Comment: What technology are you using and what is your backend?  (Apache, Tomcat, IIS, etc..)  The answer depends on that information.

Comment: I'm using Django on Apache. But methodologies can be implemented on any platform I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=Robots.txt

That will stop some bots from spidering images on your site.

Also look into a .httaccess file

http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=.htaccess

Comment: Thats all fine for normal bots who behave well. But what about malicious bots, who keep hopping over from link to link?